# SenseHat reporting temperature incorrectly - Can it be calibrated?

Tags: pi-2, sense-hat

I just received my SenseHat in the mail.  I have started with the tutorial from the raspberry pi website, but even after copying and pasting the code directly the temperature reading is showing as -41 degrees.  I'm in (northern) Australia.

Is there a way to calibrate the temperature sensor?  Or did I just get a dud board?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Pi is up to date using the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

There's an ongoing post on the RaspberryPi forum with others reporting the same problem you seem to be having: [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=148103&sid=5fe5f7bf81c38078f1a317e9e90f2225)

When I had problems with my own it was due to two processes trying to read from the sensehat at the same time and mixed up the readings which was fixed by creating functions, but if you're coping and pasting direct code from the site then it seems to be pointing at a faulty sensehat.

Make sure you've copied the code correctly and not missing anything and update and try again. Plus have a look at the link and try any recommendations suggested within the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be related to something else, but I'll make a stab at answering the question: can it be calibrated?

Any sensor can be calibrated with the right equipment and a wee bit of coding. These range from single point calibrations, simply applying an offset to the reported value, to full, multi-point, linearized calibrations.

The standard calibration we do in our lab involves the use of a NIST traceable reference with an established uncertainty of measurement modeled on BIPM's GUM. (I had links to guides here but SO doesn't think me worthy of sharing them, you'll just have to google them)

Adafruit made a great wee guide for makers on calibration [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/calibrating-sensors/why-calibrate), though it seems from reading [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=111457) that achieving accurate results from the Sense Hat might take some work. I probably wouldn't mount the hat directly to the Pi's GPIO if you need accurate readings of ambient air.